# EXCEL:What's a good replacement for SEARCH function that returns #VALUE! error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have cells that contain text with the format: IVORY / RED

I'm using a LEFT function to extract the first text string like so: 

`=LEFT(AV1440, SEARCH("/",AV1440,1)-1)`

Sometimes I run into a cell that does not contain "/", and I get a `#VALUE!` error

I've tried

```
=IF((SEARCH("/",AV1440,1)>0)`, ..above forumula.. , AV1440)
```

But if there is no `/`, that returns an error, instead of running the FALSE part of the function, because the SEARCH function NOT finding a `/` makes an error...

What is the way to fix this?

Comment: Could you share sample data with us!!

Comment: May be because of SPACE " /" in the formula is unable to match the Search String. I've edited the Formula in your post & Removed the White SPACE.  ☺

Comment: Hi Rajesh, syntax of cell data is “TEXT1 / TEXT2” , so I put space... but I  guess it is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's a simple function:
I use IFERROR, knowing there may be errors in SEARCH:
=IFERROR((LEFT(AV1440, SEARCH(" / ",AV1440,1)-1)),AV1440)

Comment: Your formula should be written like this,,`=IFERROR(LEFT(AV1440,SEARCH("/",AV1440,1)-1),AV1440)` . Remember once again you kept SPACE     `" /"`, will cause an error !! ☺

Comment: Yes, extra paranthesis is redundant!

Comment: ,,, no extra SPACE equals to one byte and the Formula uses SPACE followed by TEXT !!

Comment: If I use  this Formula,,  
         `=IFERROR(LEFT(G2,SEARCH(" /",G2,1)-1),G2)` has extra space returns `AB/CD` but if I use this one `=IFERROR(LEFT(G4,SEARCH("/",G4,1)-1),"")` returns `AB`. !!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, since you want to return the cell contents if "/" is not present, or the string up to the "/" if it is:

```
=LEFT(AV1440,SEARCH("/",AV1440&"/",1)-1)
```